# Error when sending a big int (not BigInt value) to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008

I have a service method like this:

```
[OperationContract]
public void CreateIcd9(int icd9ID, string code, string description, string specialty)
{          
    var count = from icd in clogicEntities.ICD9
                where icd.ID == icd9ID
                select icd;

    if (count.Count() >= 1)
    {
        var icd9 = clogicEntities.ICD9.Where(icd => (icd.ID == icd9ID)).SingleOrDefault();
        if (icd9 != null)
        {
            icd9.CODE = code;
            icd9.DESCRIPTION = description;
            icd9.SPECIALTY = specialty;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         ICD9 icdNew =  new ICD9()
         {
             ID = icd9ID,
             CODE = code,
             DESCRIPTION = description,
             SPECIALTY = specialty
         };                

        // Insert Icd9
        clogicEntities.ICD9.AddObject(icdNew);
    }

    clogicEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Everything is ok until today, i got a exception when call this method with `icd9ID = 1992401733`
i got this exception:

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. 
See the inner exception for details. ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table '1224-CLOGIC.dbo.ICD9'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated
```

I try to reproduce this issue but no luck, i wonder it's MAX Int problem:
2147483647 - MAX Int
1992401733 - My value
Please help me.

Comment: error seems clear: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID',". Debug the service; inspect what values it is receiving

Comment: Does your service add new `ICD9`:s in other places than this very code?

Comment: @MitchWheat: yup, but this error caused on server and hard to debug on server's service :(. I just wonder it's a int parameter issue

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: no, i checked and ICD9 just called one place on CreateIcd9 method

Comment: amazing, when i passing an ICD9 ID with int value = 1992401733 to service, serivce get 0 instead of 1992401733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my problem is the ICD9 table on EF with ID(pk) Identity(1,1) but on SQL ICD9 table - ID(pk) Identity = false so when

```
clogicEntities.ICD9.AddObject(icdNew);
```

it just pass 3 values (Code, Description, Specialty) without ID to SQL.
And reason why i passed 0 int value to service is i forgot update service reference after change parameter.

Regards.